# How to show various elements horizontally in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display the selected item as well as the previous and the next in a `RecyclerView` as I show in the image.

Here's what I need:

[image: Picture]

Any help is appreciated.

This is mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_operations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I created my recyclerview with a horizontal layout manager.

I added the adapter and temDecoration to have a separation between elements of 20 dp.

Comment: Added to the main post

Answer (score 0):

When you setting LayoutManager to your RecyclerView force it to have Horizontal layout:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, that's the basics and that's not the problem.I need to show the beginning of the next element and the previous element, show only a small part of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code snippet:

```
 yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(yourContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: The same as before

Comment: try LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(yourDesiredPosition, offset), this method will scroll the yourDesiredPosition item to top of the recyclerview with the offset you provide

Comment: Thanks again but this is not de solution i need. It is not scrolling, it is showing a central element, which is the selected item, and the elements before and after the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Fancy Cover Flow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

```
<at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        fcf:maxRotation="45"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4" />
```

Comment: It is not what I need.